# wrapping scipy.interpolate.interp1d into a function

Tags: scipy, python-3.6

am struggling to wrap scipy.interpolate.interp1d into a function.
My input pd.df:

```
In [108]: rates.tail()
Out[108]: 
               28      91      182     364
Date                                      
2017-12-18  0.0125  0.0138  0.0151  0.0169
2017-12-19  0.0125  0.0137  0.0151  0.0170
2017-12-20  0.0122  0.0138  0.0151  0.0171
2017-12-21  0.0120  0.0135  0.0154  0.0172
2017-12-22  0.0114  0.0133  0.0154  0.0172
```

This works but need to wrap it into a function with `date` as an argument:

```
x = np.array(rates.columns[0:4])
y = np.array(rates.loc[date])
f = interp1d(x, y, kind='cubic', fill_value='extrapolate')
```

Grateful for any help!

Comment: interp1d means interpolation on 1-dimensional interval. Your x-values are an array with 4 columns? What exactly is supposed to be interpolated?

Comment: it is 1-dimensional for any given date. Need to interpolate a rate on a given date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the function should take the date and a numeric value (called t below). So it could be this:

```
def interpolated(t, date): 
    x = np.array(rates.columns[0:4])
    y = np.array(rates.loc[date])
    f = interp1d(x, y, kind='cubic', fill_value='extrapolate')
    return f(t)
```

(One can also pass in `rates` if it's preferable to treat is as a parameter instead of taking it from global scope).

Comment: Thank you very much Crazy Ivan! Thats exactly what i was looking for.